# How can i improve this armature?

Tags: animation, rigging

I just started rigging. No experience. I am trying to rig this mini mech/robot. How can i make this last bone turn properly? 
Looks[image] like an easy thing to figure out but i've been struggling with it for a few hours now...
[image]

[image: I mean like this. I rotated this leg (blue) manually with bone but i want it to rotate with the cylinder (pink) by itself...]
I mean like this. I rotated this leg (blue) manually with bone but i want it to rotate with the cylinder (pink) as it should without facing one direction...

Comment: Hi. What does 'turn properly mean in this context? We don't know how it's meant to turn so we don't know what is incorrect about this.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your attention. I updated the question.